# Personalização de datagridview em c#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, datagrid, winforms

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo um projeto e estou com problemas de personalização na minha datagrid, como as informações dos dois textbox retornam na mesma datagrid eu não consigo personalizar o cabeçalho das duas, e sim de apenas uma, alguém sabe como arrumar isso, com a criação de um método ou algo parecido?

Comment: Jovem, tem como explicar melhor seu problema? Não dá pra entender nada. Você [edit] sua pergunta sempre que precisar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

André,

O que você está querendo fazer não tem como, porque são resultados diferentes, este tipo de grid não é feito para isso.

1) Se você precisa exibir dois resultados ao mesmo tempo, você vai ter que construir duas grids na tela.

2) Se você precisa apenas hora exibir um resultado, hora outro, sugiro que a montagem das colunas da grid seja dinâmicas, isso tem como você fazer

```
     private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn coluna;
     this.dgvEventos.Columns.Add(this.coluna);
```

Comment: Fiz a mudança para duas grids